# Is "to battle (something) off" correct?

Tags: grammar, phrases, vocabulary, typography

In the passage Lesson 13 from "400 Must-have words for the TOELF" by McGraw-Hill, there is a sentence that I don't understand.

"According to legend, his arrogance invoked the wrath of God, who condemned the lost crew members **to battle the waters off** the Cape of Good Hope for eternity.

I'm wondering that **to battle the waters off** is equal to **to fight the waters off** or it's just a typo and supposed to be **to battle the waters of the Cape of Good Hope**

I tried to google "battle off" but I got very limited results, not sure if it's correct.

Comment: I think it is. . *to battle the waters, off the Cape of Good Hope*.  To battle: to fight (a person, army, cause, etc.):
*We battled strong winds and heavy rains in our small boat.* http://www.dictionary.com/browse/battle

Comment: What does "off the Cape of Good Hope" mean? Does it equal "of the Cape of Good Hope"?

Comment: Off here means, *at a distance from...* - OFF preposition (AWAY FROM) http://www.dictionary.com/browse/battle

Comment: Regarding the use of "off":  The "Cape of Good Hope" refers to the peninsular land mass at the southern tip of S. America.  The waters that surround this area are the waters "off the Cape of Good Hope."

Comment: Or perhaps a land mass at the southern tip of Africa.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"[Off](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/off)" in this case refers to the crew's position in the ocean near the Cape of Good Hope.

It could be equivalently phrased as,

> According to legend, his arrogance invoked the wrath of God, who
>   condemned the lost crew members to battle the waters *by* the Cape of
>   Good Hope for eternity.

Comment: It's worth pointing out that "off" in this sense is commonly used in a nautical context. c.f. "offing" offing (n.)
"the more distant part of the open sea as seen from the shore," 1620s, a nautical term, from off (q.v.) + noun suffix -ing (1). Outside sea-jargon, it survives in the phrase in the offing (1779) which originally meant "in the distant future;" the modern sense of "impending" developed by 1914. https://www.etymonline.com/search?q=offing